# js filter + php echo $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have php page form with two select list's (First-Stage and Second-Stage) with two types of values (value-A-1,value-A-2, value-A-3, value-B-1, value-B-2), and another page where I want to show results. When user choose in First-Stage one type of value (e.g. value-A-1), in Second-Stage he will see only 'A' type values. Already it works correct by javascript filter. But after he sumbmit form, cant see results from filtered select list. When I will turn off filtering by JS, results display correclty, but ofcourse, filtering does not apply, and user is able to choose values from wrong select list.  How solve this ? heres piece of code:

page.php:

```
<form action="verify.php" name="form" id="form" method="post">
 <select id="FirstStage" name="FirstStage">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="value-A-1" id="A"> value-A-1</option>
   <option value="value-A-2" id="A"> value-A-2</option>
   <option value="value-A-3" id="A"> value-A-3</option>
   <option value="value-B-1" id="B"> value-B-1</option>
   <option value="value-B-2" id="B"> value-B-2</option>
   <option value="value-B-3" id="B"> value-B-3</option>
 </select>

 <select id="SecondStage" name="SecondStage">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="z"></option>
  <option value="value-A-aaa" >value-A-aaa</option>
  <option value="value-A-bbb" >value-A-bbb</option>
  <option value="value-A-ccc" >value-A-ccc</option>
  <option value="value-A-ddd" >value-A-ddd</option>
  <option value="value-A-eee" >value-A-eee</option>
  <option value="value-B-xxx" >value-B-xxx</option>
  <option value="value-B-yyy" >value-B-yyy</option>
  <option value="value-B-zzz" >value-B-zzz</option>
 </select>

<input type="submit" name="sendform" id="submit" value="Send a form">
```

JS:

```
jQuery.fn.filterOn = function(selection, values) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var select = this;
            var options = [];
            $(select).find('option').each(function() {
                options.push({value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text()});
            });
            $(select).data('options', options);
            $(selection).change(function(){
        $(selection + " option:selected").each(function(){
          var options = $(select).empty().data('options');
          var haystack = values[$(this).attr('id')];    
          $.each(options, function(i){
            var option = options[i];
            if($.inArray(option.value, haystack) !== -1) {
                        $(select).append(
                        $('<option>').text(option.text).val(option.value)
                        );
                    }
          });
        });
      });
        });
    };


$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
        $('#SecondStage').filterOn('#FirstStage', {
            'A': ['value-A-aaa','value-A-bbb','value-ccc','value-A-ddd','value-A-eee','z'],
          'B': ['value-B-xxx','value-B-yyy','value-B-zzz','0']   

        });
      return true;
  });
  });
```

And here's simple code from verify.php

```
  <? mysql_query("INSERT INTO form ('FirstStage','SecondStage')"); ?>
   <? echo $_POST['FirstStage']?>
   <? echo $_POST['SecondStage']?>
```

And also [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sivovokuxevu/1/), to show how it should look like for easier understand filter mechanism.

In verify.php FirstStage echo correctly, but SecondStage only when I'll disable js script

If filtering by JS is impossible to get echo result, maybe someone will suggest me, how should I do this to display values in SecondStage based on FirstStage ?

Comment: code basically works , see [demo with button to print values in html](http://jsbin.com/jezisutasija/1/edit).  You are using empty() for every selected option so if this was a `multiple` select would have problems

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for response. unfortunately, I still dont know how to fix it;/ How to resign from 'empty()' and still enjoy the filter?

Comment: `the empty` part is easy to change, just do it before you loop all the options

Comment: @charlietfl uh, im really sorry, but would u be so kindly, and modify .js for me;/ It's 4am at my local time, and I cant figure it out ;c